# I want to make mongoose as follows

Tags: mongoose

Please help me with mongodb query in nodejs.

I want a query which give me email of person by finding by it ID.

`const user=await User.findById(req.params.id).select('email');`

I have tried this

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve what you're trying to do you have to query like this:

```
const user = await User.findById(req.params.id, { email: true })
```

The second object is the projection, that is the fields you want to return from the collection, in this case will only return the email, but you can do either:

```
const user = await User.findById(req.params.id, { email: true, _id: true })
```

Or even exclude fields:

```
const user = await User.findById(req.params.id, { email: false })
```